# rJava Cannot add to classpath

Tags: java, r, classpath, rjava

When I attempt to use .jaddClassPath() or .jinit() to modify my classpath, it does not seem to have any effect on it.
Here's what I have so far

```
>>classpath
/Users/..../someFolder/
>>.jinit(classpath)
[1] 0
>>print(.jclassPath())
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rJava/java"
```

Also, I've tried this.

```
>>.jaddClassPath(classpath)
>>print(.jclassPath())
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rJava/java"
```

I'm running 
rJava - 0.9.6
R - 3.1.3
OSX Yosemite

Comment: Alright, phew! I found a fix for this...the classpath added should be an explicit list of jar files to be added to the classpath, rather than just a folder (as one would normally specify when running java on command line)

Comment: @MaraudingLily Also on the command line you would need to specify individual jars (or a glob).